# Symfony3のDBの保存について

Tags: symfony2

symfony3でお問い合せのページを作成しているのですが、DBに保存する際に、下記のエラーが出て原因が追求できません。

```
*An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO inquiry (name, email, tel, type, content) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [null, null, null, null, null]:
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null*
```

ソースは以下の通りです。

*・AppBundle/Controller/InquiryController.php*

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use AppBundle\Entity\Inquiry;
use AppBundle\Repository\UnseiRepository;

/**
 * @Route("/inquiry")
 */
class InquiryController extends Controller{
    /**
     * @Route("/")
     * @Method("get")
     */
    public function indexAction(){
        return $this->render('Inquiry/index.html.twig',
            ['form'=> $this->createInquiryForm()->createView()]
        );
    }
    public function createInquiryForm(){
        return $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('name',TextType::class)
        ->add('email',TextType::class)
        ->add('tel',TextType::class,[
            'required'=> false,
        ])
        ->add('type',ChoiceType::class,[
            'choices' => [
                '公演について',
                'その他',
            ],
            'expanded' => true,
        ])
        ->add('content',TextareaType::class)
        ->add('submit',SubmitType::class,[
            'label' => '送信',
        ])
        ->getForm();
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/")
     * @Method("post")
     */
    public function indexPostAction(Request $request){
        $inquiry = new Inquiry();
        $form = $this->createInquiryForm(Register::class, $inquiry);
        $form->handleRequest($request);


        if($form->isValid()){
            $data = $form->getData();

            //POSTデータをDBに保存
            $inquiry = new Inquiry();
            $inquiry->setName($data["name"]);
            $inquiry->setEmail($data["email"]);
            $inquiry->setTel($data["tel"]);
            $inquiry->setType($data["type"]);
            $inquiry->setContent($data["content"]);

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($inquiry);
            $em->flush();

            $message = \ Swift_Message::newInstance()
                ->setSubject("Webサイトからのお問い合わせ")
                ->setFrom('@gmail.com')
                ->setTo('@yahoo.co.jp')
                ->setBody(
                    $this->renderView(
                        'mail/inquiry.txt.twig',
                        ['data'=>'$data']
                    )
                );
            $this->get('mailer')->send($message);

            return $this->render('Inquiry/complete.html.twig');
        }
        return $this->render('Inquiry/index.html.twig',['form'=> $form->createView()]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/complete")
     */
    public function completeAction(){
        return $this->render('Inquiry/complete.html.twig');
    }
}
```

*・AppBundle/Entity/Inquiry.php*

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Inquiry
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="inquiry")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\InquiryRepository")
 */
class Inquiry
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
     private $id;

     /**
      * @var string
      *
      * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=30)
      *
      *
      */
     private $name;

     /**
      * @var string
      *
      * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=100)
      *
      *
      */
     private $email;

     /**
      * @var string
      *
      * @ORM\Column(name="tel", type="string", length=20, nullable=true)
      *
      *
      */
     private $tel;

     /**
      * @var string
      *
      * @ORM\Column(name="type", type="string", length=20)
      *
      *
      */
     private $type;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="text")
     *
     *
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set tel
     *
     * @return varchar
     */
    public function setTel()
    {
        return $this->tel;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @return varchar
     */
    public function setName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @return varchar
     */
    public function setEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set type
     *
     * @return varchar
     */
    public function setType()
    {
        return $this->type;
    }

    /**
     * Set content
     *
     * @return varchar
     */
    public function setContent()
    {
        return $this->content;
    }


   /**
    * Get name
    *
    * @return string
    */
   public function getName()
   {
        return $this->name;
   }

   /**
    * Get email
    *
    * @return string
    */
   public function getEmail()
   {
       return $this->email;
   }

   /**
    * Get tel
    *
    * @return string
    */
   public function getTel()
   {
       return $this->tel;
   }

  /**
   * Get type
   *
   * @return string
   */
  public function getType()
  {
      return $this->type;
  }

  /**
   * Get content
   *
   * @return string
   */
  public function getContent()
  {
      return $this->content;
  }
}
```

Controllerの以下の時点で各$dataのvalueがnullになることを確認しており、上記エラーメッセージが出るのだと思いますが、何故valueがnullになるのか原因が分かりません。

```
$inquiry = new Inquiry();
$inquiry->setName($data["name"]);
$inquiry->setEmail($data["email"]);
$inquiry->setTel($data["tel"]);
$inquiry->setType($data["type"]);
$inquiry->setContent($data["content"]);
```

また、Entityで以下のように引数もセットして試したましたが、エラーは解消しませんでした。
どなたか原因がわかる方、ご教示願います。

```
public function setTel($tel)
{
    return $this->tel;
}
```

Comment: `Inquery`の`setName`functionの定義が`getName`と同一に見えますが、質問の誤記でしょうか?

Comment: ありがとうございます。自己解決できました。